# Unknown format error on running examples on coral board along with coral camera

Tags: opencv, v4l2, google-coral, google-aiy

I was running examples from google coral. They worked fine on my coral board. Then i modified the examples after following this [post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/21/increasing-webcam-fps-with-python-and-opencv/) to increase fps output  of camera.

The details of platform :

```
mendel@coral2:~$ uname -a
Linux coral2 4.14.98-imx #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 8 23:28:21 UTC 2019 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

The example runs fine with usb camera (standard one) however with coral camera results in following error. (**VISIBLE IN SYSLOGS**)

```
Jun  1 10:32:28 coral2 kernel: [378824.885837] unknown pixelformat:'BGR3'
Jun  1 10:32:28 coral2 kernel: [378824.889798] mx6s-csi 30a90000.csi1_bridge: Fourcc format (0x33524742) invalid.
Jun  1 10:32:28 coral2 kernel: [378824.897302] unknown pixelformat:'YV12'
Jun  1 10:32:28 coral2 kernel: [378824.901344] mx6s-csi 30a90000.csi1_bridge: Fourcc format (0x32315659) invalid.
Jun  1 10:32:28 coral2 kernel: [378824.908784] unknown pixelformat:'411P'
Jun  1 10:32:28 coral2 kernel: [378824.912753] mx6s-csi 30a90000.csi1_bridge: Fourcc format (0x50313134) invalid.
Jun  1 10:32:28 coral2 kernel: [378824.920308] unknown pixelformat:'MJPG'
Jun  1 10:32:28 coral2 kernel: [378824.924268] mx6s-csi 30a90000.csi1_bridge: Fourcc format (0x47504a4d) invalid.
Jun  1 10:32:28 coral2 kernel: [378824.931818] unknown pixelformat:'JPEG'
Jun  1 10:32:28 coral2 kernel: [378824.935778] mx6s-csi 30a90000.csi1_bridge: Fourcc format (0x4745504a) invalid.
```

Steps to produce error

1. git clone https://github.com/deepanshu-yadav/coral_bug.git
2. ./download_models.sh
3. cd opencv
4. ./install_requirements.sh
5. python3 detect.py

To sum it up it only reads the first frame and never shows the subsequent frames.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have also reached out to us via our private support channel, but I'm pasting it here for other to reference also.

Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this issue on my side using your code. A quick look at the code base, it appears that you haven't commit your changes.
On another note, I don't believe this is going to work in the first place. This is because the Camera module that we ship doesn't have supports for BGR3 format and only YUYV. You can confirm this with this command:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext --device /dev/video0
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Type: Video Capture

        [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 720x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1280x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1920x1080
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 2592x1944
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 0x0
```

Comment: The commit is [this](https://github.com/deepanshu-yadav/coral_bug/commit/f268e06746744dab81f2bba500c849bb11f25f2a).  And the output is same for v4l2.

Comment: Did you checked out SYSLOGS ?

Comment: @DeepanshuYadav I see, it's definitely in the syslog. Sorry, I thought it would be in the stdout, anyhow, I was able to run the demo without issue. That article is long, which technique did you use? I would avoid threading at all cost unless you absolutely know how to control the threads. Linux kernel will not allow multiple threads to access a the pcie/usb resource at the same time so invoke will surely crashes.

Comment: [Edit] Just FYI, I mean threading meaning having multiple threads invoking the tpu resources at the same time (that's not allowed). If you can queue up all the frames and feed it to the tpu one by one then that's okay.

Comment: Thanks I will try queuing mechanism given [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/06/faster-video-file-fps-with-cv2-videocapture-and-opencv/) and then discuss. By the way the same error did  not occur for usb camera. That was strange.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the command I sent you. The source to `/dev/video0` points to to the coral's camera, which shows it ONLY supports YUYV. I'm not sure about the changes you've made but based on the logs, it seems to be forcing other pixel format such as BGR3, JPEG, ...
Your usb camera most likely have supports for this which is the reason why you didn't run into the issue. Check with: `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext --device /dev/video1`